# xinetd как настроить на запуск скрипта python?

Tags: python, linux, администрирование, сетевое-программирование

при коннекте к серверу как я понял должен запускаться скрипт
вот сам скрипт

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import sys
print "Enter your name:\n"
sys.stdout.flush()
my_name = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
print "Your name is %s" % my_name
sys.stdout.flush()
quit()
```

файл /etc/xinetd.conf

```
 # Simple configuration file for xinetd
#
# Some defaults, and include /etc/xinetd.d/

defaults
{

# Please note that you need a log_type line to be able to use log_on_success
# and log_on_failure. The default is the following :
# log_type = SYSLOG daemon info

}

includedir /etc/xinetd.d
service mon
{
        port = 9090
        socket_type = dgram
        protocol = tcp
        user = root
        group = root
        server = /root/monserv/first.py
        type = UNLISTED
        wait = yes
        instances = 20
        cps = 20 10
        disable = no
}
```

Что не так? Почему оно не работает? Как сделать правильно? Браузер уже трещит от вкладок с инфой, по которой вроде как все правильно...

Comment: dgram менял на stream - не помогло

Answer (score 1):

проблема решена! Трабл был в доступе к **/root/monserv/first.py**, после перемещения скрипта в **/usr/** всё заработало